# SATA hard disk not detected through SATA to USB adapter

Tags: sata

I have this converter which allows to connect IDE or SATA to a PC through a USB port.

I have connected a SATA hard disk without supplying power but the PC didn’t detect it.

Is the power through the USB port enough to power up the SATA hard disk?

I have used a mini IDE Disk without power and worked fine.

Comment: Voting to close. This question is over a decade old, the details are sparse at best and the implication here is the original poster is attempting to use 2.5" SATA to USB cable and not a 3.5" SATA to USB cable that typically comes with (and requires) an external AC adapter to power the 3.5" drive itself. People fall into this trap fairly regularly because a basic SATA to USB cable for 2.5" drives costs about 1/2 the price of a similar adapter for 3.5" drives that comes with the AC adapter.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably going to need additional power to get the hard drive running. Notebook drives use a lot less power than your standard 3.5 inch desktop drive. Most adapters come with two USB plugs one for data and power and one for just power. It also depends on the type of drive and size I have a 2.5 160GB drive that is fine with just one USB connection but my 2.5 320 GB Western Digital needs both USB adapters plugged in. You can always get an additional adapter just for power if your current one doesn't have two plugs.

Comment: Thanx a lot Kyle :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a 2.5 inch SATA hard drive, it should get its 5v power via the USB port.

If it is a 3.5 inch SATA hard drive, you will need to connect 5v power to the hard drive.

Comment: Thanx a lot Moab :)

Comment: I have some 2.5 drives that don't work with just usb power.. not sure why just something I noticed (they are all bigger than 320GB).

Comment: My Drive is 3.5 inch 160GB SATA. I don't have the power supply for the adapter at the moment. I'll reply when I check it with power. Once again thanx a lot both of you :)

Comment: @ Kyle, some older laptops single USB ports do not supply enough power for a 2.5 inch hard drive, they make special usb cables that connect to 2 usb ports to power the drive, not sure if this is your issue or not.

Answer (score -1):

In the specs of any HDD you will find the Voltage AND Current it needs. Some of them come for 1A and 5V, and most USB ports can't handle that amount of power(USB 2.0 allows 500mA, USB 3.0 allows 900mA). It's not about capacity, I have seen some of 1Tb that require 600mA, and some 320Gb that require 1A. Those "1A HDD" requires dual USB power or external power.

Answer (score -3):

Your PC's hard disk requires 5v 0.73A input for power up and your laptop gives 5v 1A output. I think you require an external power source, or you can add a resistor to your cable's circuit, if you can manage.

Comment: Adding a resistor makes no sense, and where did you get the current specs?  Please don't post an answer unless you have factual information to contribute.